# CALayer: archiving then unarchiving data does not match original object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIButton with a UITextView as it's subview. The UITextView has 1 layer which the border is colored and has a width of 1. When I archive the UIButton then unarchive it, the border color and the border width becomes nil. If I set the layer background color, it will stay the same when archived then unarchived, which makes this bug very confusing.

```
UIButton textButton = ...

NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:textButton];
UIButton *textButton2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

The lldb debug output shows that the border color disappears

```
(lldb) po  [[[textButton subviews] firstObject] layer] <CALayer:0x13445780; position = CGPoint (150 50); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 300 100); delegate = <UITextView: 0xdb20000; frame = (0 0; 300 100); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x13446430>; layer = <CALayer: 0x13445780>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>; sublayers = (<_UITextTiledLayer: 0x13448e80>, <CALayer: 0x13445d90>); masksToBounds = YES; allowsGroupOpacity = YES; borderColor = <CGColor 0xc09b6d0> [<CGColorSpace 0xbf28210> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)] ( 0.378437 0.5 0.13035 1 ); backgroundColor = <CGColor 0xbed1e10> [<CGColorSpace 0xbe65e70> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceGray)] ( 0 0 ); borderWidth = 1>

(lldb) po [[[textButton2 subviews] firstObject] layer] <CALayer:0x13443fe0; position = CGPoint (150 50); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 300 100); delegate = <UITextView: 0xdb2aa00; frame = (0 0; 300 100); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x13432ed0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x13443fe0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>; sublayers = (<_UITextTiledLayer: 0x134447f0>, <CALayer: 0x13434740>); masksToBounds = YES; allowsGroupOpacity = YES; backgroundColor = <CGColor 0xbed1e10> [<CGColorSpace 0xbe65e70> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceGray)] ( 0 0 )>
```

Is there something special about the border color? Or is this really a bug?

Comment: This is most likely caused if UIButton only archives its own properties